# Unable to install pymgclient for memgraphdb

Tags: memgraphdb

I am trying to install pymgclient for memgraphdb. I am following the instructions mentioned at this link:

https://memgraph.github.io/pymgclient/introduction.html

In the first step, it says we have to run the following commands inside the source directory.

```
$ python3 setup.py build
$ python3 setup.py install
```

However, inside the src directory of the mgclient folder, there is no `setup.py` file. Where can I find that `setup.py` file?

Answer (score 2):

`setup.py` is located in the root directory of the project source. So you would do:

```
git clone https://github.com/memgraph/pymgclient
cd pymgclient
python3 setup.py install
```

Note #1: You might need root privileges for the last command.

Note #2: pymgclient is just a wrapper around the C client library, mgclient (https://github.com/memgraph/mgclient), so you will need to install that first to be able to install and run pymgclient.